# MongoDB. Select fields existing in other cillection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have two collections. I need to select documents from the first one by the criteria that field value exists in the second collection. For example:

User_Item collection has documents like below

```
{
  '_id' ...,
  'uid' : 123,
  'iid' : 'a123',
  'quantity' : 10
}
```

The second collection contains some item's like below

```
{
  '_id' ...,
  'iid' : 'a456',
  'name' : 'someItem'
}
```

I need to obtain the sample by the item id's ('iid') which coincide in both collections. The expected result is presented.

```
{
 '_id'  : ...,
 'uid' : 123,
 'iid': 'a123',
 'name' : 'item123'
 }
```

I've used $lookup in the user_items from the items but it returns EVERY documents in the first collection and there're a lot of empty arrays. I want to avoid it.

In case of $lookup in items from user_items it will return an array of users. It's not the result desired too.

Is there some options in the lookup, or may be another solution of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.User_Item.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "second",
    "localField": "iid",
    "foreignField": "iid",
    "as": "second"
  }},
  { "$match": { "second": { "$ne": [] }}},
  { "$addFields": {
    "name": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$second.name", 0] }
  }},
  { "$project": { "second": 0 }}
])
```

Comment: @CatherineNosova Updated my answer. Just use `$match` stage after `$lookup`.